# Get mdslider value in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a input field in which i want to show the value of the matSlider

```
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <mat-slider class="example-full-width" 
    [max]=""
    [min]="min"
    [step]="step"
    [thumb-label]="thumbLabel"
    (input)="onInputChange($event)"></mat-slider>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input type="number" matInput formControlName="txtMinPriceRange"  placeholder="Minimum" [value]="minValue">
    </mat-form-field>  
  </div>
```

right now I am using (input)="onInputChange($event)" is there any other way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do it by 2 ways:

1) There is no need to call on component side, by using `localVariable`:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <mat-slider class="example-full-width" 
    [max]=""
    [min]="min"
    [step]="step"
    [thumb-label]="thumbLabel"
    #matslider></mat-slider>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12">
  <input type="number" placeholder="Minimum" [value]="matslider?.value">
</div>
```

2) with `Component` side :

```
// component
export class SliderOverviewExample {
  matslider2 = 0;

  changeMatslider2(slider) {
    this.matslider2 = slider.value ;
  }
}

// template side
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <mat-slider class="example-full-width" 
    [max]=""
    [min]="min"
    [step]="step"
    [thumb-label]="thumbLabel"
    (input)='changeMatslider2($event)'></mat-slider>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12">
  <input type="number" placeholder="Minimum" [value]="matslider2">
</div>
```

Here is the link to working demo with both implementation :

https://plnkr.co/edit/JlTyXM?p=preview

Comment: @AbhishekSingh, glad to hear that.

Comment: Is there a way to pass the value to the component side? That would really help me

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/JlTyXM?p=preview @Davtho1983 , please check my updated answer