# How to set two way databinding on ng5 material slider value

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've got this application that uses angular5 together with material.
While some examples and extra docs are lacking, development went fairly smooth. Until now, when I stumble upon this slider issue that I can't fix.

In my component I declare a `myValue = 3` that is used as the default value of a `<mat-slider>`. I also plot this value in a `<h2>` right above it.

I can drag the slider and see the thumbLabel update. However, the `{{myValue}}` in the h2 does not update.

Do I need to manually 'get' the updated number? I can't seem to figure out how they are doing it in the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/slider/overview).

I was thinking that maybe it had something to do with 'encapsulation' being loaded, but adding that made no difference.

How can I update {{myValue}} automatically whenever the slider value changes?

EDIT:

I'm using Angular 5 & material 5.2.4, not ng6. You can find an example of the code on: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-bbfwhn

---

EDIT2:

I found this post: [How to get current value of angular material slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959135/how-to-get-current-value-of-angular-material-slider). It appears to work in my case, but I'm hoping there is a more elegant solution for this than writing a separate function in the component just to get the value back.

Also, this examples shows another easy way to get the value in the viewport: adding `#matslider` to the slider and getting the value in the html using `{{matslider.value}}`. I do however also need `myValue` in the component itself (to pass along to a provider).

---

EDIT3:

A dynamic way to solve this issue (when you have a lot of sliders) that expands upon [How to get current value of Angular Material slider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959135/how-to-get-current-value-of-angular-material-slider) is this:

component.ts:

```
setSlidervalue(event: any){
  this[event.source._elementRef.nativeElement.attributes.valvar.nodeValue] = event.value;
}
```

component.html:

```
<h2>slidervalue: {{testValue}}</h2>
<mat-slider min="1" max="5" step="0.5" [(value)]="testValue" (input)='setSlidervalue($event)' valVar="testValue"></mat-slider>
```

Using this solution, you can add more sliders like so:

```
<h2>onothervalue: {{someValue}}</h2>
    <mat-slider min="1" max="5" step="0.5" [(value)]="someValue" (input)='setSlidervalue($event)' valVar="someValue"></mat-slider>
```

The proposed solution works but is far from elegant. Leaving this question open in the hopes of finding a cleaner way to solve this.

Comment: Use ngModel for two way binding. <mat-slider     [(ngModel)]="myValue" >

Comment: How did you implement two-way binding?

Comment: check the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-bbfwhn

Answer (score 6):

Use `ngModel` for two way binding.

app.component.html

```
<mat-slider [(ngModel)]="value"></mat-slider>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  value = 1000;
}
```

Comment: While that does seem to work in 6.0.0-rc.1 (as is used by StackBlitz) it does not appear to work in 5.2.4 (last stable) which is the version actually used by my app. (I'm trying to set it up in StackBlitz using my exact version to make sure that it's not my setup causing the problem)

Comment: Great answer for ng6 + material 6.0.0. But it doesn't work for n5 + mat 5.2.4 (latest stable). As shown here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-69p3xd

Answer (score 3):

Just add "#slider"

```
<h2>slider value: {{slider.value}}</h2>
<mat-slider #slider min="1" max="5" step="0.5" thumbLabel></mat-slider>
```

see:[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-2omyzm)

Answer (score 1):

In my instance (Angular 15) I needed to use a separate input element with matSliderThumb attribute.
In that version, the input gets bound to your data.

```
<mat-slider min="0" [max]="myDynamicMax" step="1">
  <input matSliderThumb [ngModel]="myDynamicPosition">
</mat-slider>
```